# Writing DbContext extension method

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-core

When I write DbContext extension method, It doesn't work. I can't access to the method from DbContext object. What is the problem ?

```
namespace Data
{
 public static class DbContextExtensions
 {
    public static bool AreThereAnyChanges(this DbContext context)
        => context.ChangeTracker
            .Entries()
            .Any(x => x.State == EntityState.Modified ||
                      x.State == EntityState.Added ||
                      x.State == EntityState.Deleted);
 }
}

using Data;
namespace Demo
{
 public partial class KybInfrastructureDemoDbContext : DbContext, IDatabaseContext
 {
    public KybInfrastructureDemoDbContext() { }

    public KybInfrastructureDemoDbContext(DbContextOptions<KybInfrastructureDemoDbContext> options)
        : base(options) { 
           // 'DbContext' does not contain a definition for 'AreThereAnyChanges'
           bool change = base.AreThereAnyChanges(); 
    }
  } 
}
```

Comment: Maybe you could try extending this instead of base.

Comment: It might be because you are in a constructor.  Does it work outside the constructor?  Are you getting a compile error or a runtime error.  What is the error? Saying _"It doesn't work"_ doesn't tell us much

Comment: What happens when you try invoking it like: `DbContextExtensions.AreThereAnyChanges(base)`?

Comment: @Marko Radivojević My goal is to write an extension method to DbContext class.

Comment: @tnw I added Data namespace to KybInfrastructureDemoDbContext.cs usings. So I'm expecting to access to extension methods in the Data namespace.

Comment: @Flydog57 It's a compiler error CS0117

Comment: @StriplingWarrior I got CS0175 compiler error

Comment: It's good to paste the error text as well.  We don't memorize the error codes.  In this case, it's _"'type' does not contain a definition for 'identifier'"_

Comment: I understand. I was saying what D Stanley pointed out in his answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`base` is not an object reference. It is a keyword to force the compiler to bind to a base class member instead of an override on the current class.  Since there is no `AreThereAnyChanges` defined on the base class, the compiler throws an error.

Use `this` instead. And since `this` is a `DbContext`, the compiler should find the appropriate extension method:

```
bool change = this.AreThereAnyChanges();
```

Note that if there were *also* an `AreThereAnyChanges` extension method specific to `KybInfrastructureDemoDbContext`, then you could still bind to the `DbContext` extention by casting `this`:

```
bool change = ((DbContext)this).AreThereAnyChanges();
```